# python import from parent directories '__init__.py' file

Tags: python, flask, import

I am working on a flask app with the following structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── forms
│   │   └── login.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── user.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   └── login.html
│   └── views
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── login.py
```

in `app/__init__.py` I am creating an instance of the LoginManager extension:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import app_config
from flask_login import LoginManager

def create_app(config_mode='development'):
    """Wrapping app creation in factory according to specified config."""

    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

    ...

    # register login manager extension
    login = LoginManager(app)

    return app
```

I now need to import `login` in `app/models/user.py` in order to provide the `user_loader` implementation:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin


from . import db
from .. import login

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    """User model."""

    ...

@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

However, any attempt to do this fails with:

```
from .. import login
ImportError: cannot import name 'login'
```

My question is: is there any way to import from a parent directories `__init__.py` file, or am I making some other mistake here?

I tried a number of different combinations of absolute and relative imports but all yield the same result, and searched extensively on SO and google, but did not find a direct answer to my question. I would like to keep the `user.py` module the current directory as the directory structure is nice and concisely organized.

Thanks in advance

edit: clarified import location

Comment: `..` goes up not down. Use `from app.models import login`

Comment: my bad, I worded the description poorly. i need to import from the app directory, not the models directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the instance of `LoginManager` out of `create_app` function. And then you can configure it for login with `init_app` method.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask-login import LoginManager

login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Comment: you, sir, are a live saver. it works like a charm. Thanks a lot