# Import error in a Flask application

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm building a flask application and using an extension [flask-marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to serialise [flask-alchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/) query output. The problem is I'm unable to import marshmallow object to models, where I'm using it.

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

# local imports
from config import app_config

db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_message = "You must be logged in to access this page."


    ## this is the object, I want to import to models
    ma = Marshmallow(app)
    ##
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    from app import models


    from .operations import operations as ops_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(ops_blueprint)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)



    return app
```

I'm trying to import the ma object in the following **models.py** file:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

## here I'm importing ma, but getting the error mentioned in the last part of this question
from app import db, login_manager, ma
##
from sqlalchemy import func


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    """
    Creates a users table
    """
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password should not be readable')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

Getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = create_app(config_name)
  File "/Users/yousufsyed/Desktop/right/app/__init__.py", line 32, in create_app
    from app import models
  File "/Users/yousufsyed/Desktop/right/app/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import ma, db, login_manager
ImportError: cannot import name ma
```

Cannot figure out how to import **ma** in the second file? Any pointers?

Comment: Why would you want to import `ma` in your models? Anyhow, the problem is that `ma` is defined once the `create_app` function is called, it's not available earlier.

Comment: I need it to define output that I can then use in views. I'm very new to the flask ecosystem, how can I make it available earlier? It needs the app object and app object is created only in create_app.

Comment: Where do you define `app` to begin with, it isn't created anywhere?

Comment: @PaxVobiscum Its created on first line of create_app method [    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
]

Comment: That is a local variable. The scope of this is not available outside of the function. How would `models.py` know what `app` is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python import from parent directories '\_\_init\_\_.py' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087442/python-import-from-parent-directories-init-py-file)